# Unable to call initWithFrameStyleURL method for MQMapView in my native script plugin for iOS

Tags: angular, nativescript, mapquest

I am trying to create a plugin for mapQuest in nativescript.

When I call 
MQMapView.alloc().initWithFrameStyleURL(CGRectMake(0, 0,100, 100), MGLStyle.streetsStyleURL);
OR 
MQMapView.new()

It just get stuck there no error or nothing shows up.

I would like to create instance for MQMapview in nativeScript

Comment: I don't see such method exposed in `MQMapView`. What is prints if you do `console.log(MQMapView.alloc().initWithFrameStyleURL)`?

Comment: initWithFrameStyleURL is presenting the parent class. I tried using new but its also not provide any instance. Basically I was trying to create instance for MQMapView class